# How do i display React Components inline

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to put multiple React Components in the same line so i can later scroll through them. Sadly React and Material UI dont want to play ball. Card Components are just a standard div element with some text and an image inside. Any idea how i can make them inline?

```
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card.js'


const Carousel = () => {
    return (
    <>
        <Box component='div' display='inline'>
            <Card/>
        </Box>
        <Box component='div' display='inline'>
            <Card/>
        </Box>
    </>
    )
}

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you referring to `inline` the css property or you just want the two divs to display on one line?

Comment: @codemonkey 2 divs or more to be displayed on one line. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Single Line Grid List like detailed here: https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list

Comment: Wow thanks, now im kinda embarrassed that i didnt see that before and it looks better than my design too. Thanks
But otherwise it is not possible to make them in the same line?

Comment: I think it should be possible. Material UI uses Flexbox underneath anyway. However, I think it would be far too easier to modify the Grid List around your needs than to implement something on your own.